# visualforce with lightning styling looks different on mobile compared to desktop

Tags: visualforce, lightning, mobile

**Sample code**:

```
<apex:page  docType="html-5.0" 
            lightningStyleSheets="true" 
            showHeader="false" 
            sidebar="false" 
            standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Desktop**:

[image]

**iphone X**

[image]

I am not much of a css expert. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that as per [VF guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_apply.htm) API version 47:

> Apex tags such as `<apex:pageblock>` and `<apex:inputField>` are not yet supported for use with SLDS.

But considering other recommendation from same guide, you can somewhat improve the font rendering in responsive display by applying `<apex:slds />` to your page and wrap your code in a scoping class, `<div class="slds-scope">...</div>` as follows:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" 
            lightningStyleSheets="true" 
            showHeader="false" 
            sidebar="false" 
            standardStylesheets="false">

  <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
  <apex:slds />

    <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
    <div class="slds-scope">
     <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

which gives this:

[image]